# Textbox as integer?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have made a textbox which is only able to contain numbers. However, I want to multiply the number written in the textbox by 2, and then display it. For some reason the displayed number is always 0. I am using Visual Basic express edition 2008

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress
    Dim TextBox1 As Integer

    If Asc(e.KeyChar) < 48 Or Asc(e.KeyChar) > 57 Xor Asc(e.KeyChar) = 8 Xor Asc(e.KeyChar) = 44 Xor Asc(e.KeyChar) = 46 Then
        e.Handled = True
        MessageBox.Show(TextBox1 * 2)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You are not assigning a value to the TextBox1 local Integer.

Comment: A Textbox **never** contains numbers, only text.  "1234567890" are *numerals*.  Turn on Option Strict to learn more about Types

Comment: There's  no need to reinvent the wheel: [NumericUpDown](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You created an int variable

```
Dim TextBox1 As Integer
```

Which defaults to 0.  Then you multiply it by 2.

```
MessageBox.Show(TextBox1 * 2)
```

0 * 2 = 0.

You need to get the Value from the TextBox, parse the text to an int (`int.Parse`), then multiply that value.

Comment: Since this is in the KeyPress event, the value of TextBox1 won't have changed, so you'd need to parse the value from `e.KeyChar` or change to using the TextChanged event.

Comment: @AWinkle I'll bow to you on when these events fire.  What's for sure is that OP is in a world of incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

Try doing this:

```
Dim TextBox1 As Integer
TextBox1 = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text)
```

Answer (score 1):

If It is a text box you are using, and not just a variable you've named textbox1 then simply use 
'messageBox.show(CInt(TextBox1.Text) * 2))'

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the example below will help...

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress

    Select Case Convert.ToInt16(e.KeyChar)

        Case 48 To 57 ' only allow numbers in this Case
            MessageBox.Show(CStr(CDec(e.KeyChar.ToString) * 2))

        Case Else ' handle everything else here
            e.Handled = True
    End Select
End Sub
```